# How to create an email gateway with two email server as backend email server

Tags: linux, email, gateway, james

I know we can use Nginx as a reverse proxy to forward traffics to multiple upstream server. Now I want to know how can I get such thing for email? I want to have an email gateway or email proxy to deliver the received emails to the proper email servers. something like the following pseudo code:

```
server {
    listen 25;
    server_name mydomain1.com;
    forward to server mydomain1.com;
}
server {
    listen 25;
    server_name mydomain2.com;
    forward to server mydomain2.com;
}
```

When the server receives info@mydomain1.com for instance, it delivers the email to server mydomain1.com and whenever the server (gateway) receives info@mydomain2.com it is forwarded to mydoamin2.com. mydoamin1.com and mydoamin2.com are the backend email servers.
Which is the proper open source service can I use and configure for this purpose? Does apache james can be used as the gateway layer in front of multiple email servers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is not "Programming" realated and is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Good old `sendmail` provided anything required to do that, and I really think that postfix can also does it by simple configuration, because it is close to the basics for a SMTP MTA. Apache Jame can probably do it too, but it seems to be much heavier than postfix.

Comment: Thanks. You mean sendmail can be used as an email gateway for multiple backends?may you please give an example?